# How does pthread_self() always succeed?

Tags: c, pthreads

When I was learning pthread, the manual says `pthread_self()` always succeeds.

> ERRORS
>
> This function always succeeds.

How does that happen? How do we determine whether a function will always succeed?

I tried to find the answer from the code, and I encounter the following code:

```
# define THREAD_SELF \
  ({ struct pthread *__self;                                      \
     asm ("movl %%gs:%c1,%0" : "=r" (__self)                      \
      : "i" (offsetof (struct pthread, header.self)));            \
     __self;})
```

I didn't see the field `header.self` in `struct pthread`, did I look into the wrong definition? And what does the `%c1` mean? Is the input `i` unused?

Comment: since you're calling the function from your thread, it has an id and the function returns it. It always succeeds because your thread is running and has an id.

Comment: If this ever did fail, you have worse problems than the actual failure - something big must have gone wrong elsewhere.

Comment: If it fails, your app is flatlined and on life-support.  Turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_self()` returns the identifier of the currently-running thread.  It has to be called by the "currently running thread", so that identifier must exist.

How can that fail?  It's the same way that we all assume that expressions such as `x++;` or `y = x / z` can't fail.

Comment: It's similar to `getpid()` and `getppid()` which `"are always successful"` as described in `man getpid`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Exactly.  There's an assumption of "it has to work" at a very basic level when writing code.  Things get real difficult when that falls apart - like [this hardware problem where bytes read from disk into a buffer not 8-byte aligned don't go where they're supposed to...](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/fs.d/ufs/mkfs/mkfs.c#430)